# Merging yaml documents together based on specific key in slice of maps in golang

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

Given the example below. I want to overlay B onto A based on the key `type`. So, if the same `type` exists in both A and B, then B will overwrite A, otherwise it just gets appended. If something exists in A, that doesn't exist in B, then it also gets appended to the slice.

A

```
service: myservice
contacts:
  - type: slack
    contact: https://slack.com/SDGSDF
  - type: email
    contact: email@email.com
```

B

```
service: myservice
contacts:
  - type: slack
    contact: https://slack.com/FVJTYSAFA
```

Overlay B on A

```yaml
service: myservice
contacts:
  - type: slack
    contact: https://slack.com/FVJTYSAFA # Slack gets updated
  - type: email # email gets appended to slice
    contact: email@email.com
```

I have a tried a few things and It seems like there could be multiple ways to solve this problem.

1. custom Unmarshaler (seems like this could work). Where I would unmarshal the yaml and then unmarshal it again, but the second time merging it together. Not entirely sure if this is possible though.
2. Converting it to a `map[string]interface{}` and trying to just process it this way
3. Unmarshal each yaml document into a struct and then merge the structs together with reflect
4. Something I don't know yet?

I dug into unmarshaling both into a struct and then merging those structs. I got close, but get lost when using reflect and how I would go about doing what I want to do.

When I try using something like `map[string]interface{}`, I'm not sure how to dig deeper into the yaml object. For instance, I know I can do something like

```golang
var y1 = []byte(`
service: myservice
contacts:
  - type: "slack"
    contact: "https://slack.com/SDGSDF"
  - type: "email"
    contact: "email@email.com"
`)

func main() {
    data:= map[string]interface{}{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(y1, &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

But then how do i loop over contacts and compare using the `map[string]interface{}` method?

I am trying to learn go, so sorry if I don't phrase this correctly or I am missing something. Thanks for the help!